# Adding ContourLabels changes contour colors?

Tags: plotting, bugs

**Bug introduced in 8 or earlier and persists through 11.0.1 or later. Fixed in 13.2.0 or earlier.**

---

I have an array `s5` I want to plot using `ListContourPlot`

```
s5 = Import[
  "https://github.com/downloads/stackmma/Attachments/data_13545.m"];
ListContourPlot[s5, InterpolationOrder -> 6, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
    ContourLabels -> True, ColorFunctionScaling -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphic with labels]

Note, the blue spot in the corner. Turning off `ContourLabels` gives

```
ListContourPlot[s5, InterpolationOrder -> 6, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
  ContourLabels -> False, ColorFunctionScaling -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The resulting images have entriely different colors. I cannot understand why adding `ContourLabels` should change the colors, and for other data sets it seems to not do that.
I ended up using a workaround that involved making one of the pictures mostly transparent and overlaying it with a picture that had the right colors. This I think is actually the simplest workaround proposed so far:

```
wl = ListContourPlot[s5, InterpolationOrder -> 6, 
ColorFunction -> (Append[ColorData["TemperatureMap"][#1], 0] &), 
ContourLabels -> True, Contours -> contours];

nl = ListContourPlot[s5, InterpolationOrder -> 6, 
ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", Contours -> contours];
Show[nl,wl]
```

Comment: You may want to read my additional notes to your approach in the middle of my answer.

Comment: From WRI: It does appear that ListContourPlot is not behaving properly. I have forwarded an incident report to our developers with the information you provided. I included your email address so that you can be notified when a Mathematica with this corrected is released.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Workaround

For a detailed discussion about this bug, see below. Here is a workaround:

```
ListContourPlotWithLabel[data_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{grlabl, gr},
  {grlabl, gr} = 
   ListContourPlot[data, ContourLabels -> #, 
      Evaluate[
       FilterRules[{opts}, Options[ListContourPlot]]]] & /@ {True, 
     False};
  With[{pts = 
     Dispatch@
      MapIndexed[First[#2] -> #1 &, 
       First@Cases[grlabl, {{_Real, _Real} ..}, {2}]]},
   gr /. GraphicsComplex[fst_, snd_] :> 
     GraphicsComplex[fst, Append[snd,
       Cases[grlabl, Text[__], Infinity] /. 
        Text[what_, pt_] :> Text[what, pt /. pts]]
      ]
   ]
  ]
```

This function creates always a plot with label. All other options can just be used as usual. Let's apply it to your data (I uploaded it to the site):

```
data = Import[
   "https://github.com/downloads/stackmma/Attachments/data_13545.m"];
ListContourPlotWithLabel[data, InterpolationOrder -> 6, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**What the workaround does:** Usually, the workaround should be a one-liner but due to another bug, it is not possible to call `Normal` on a labeled `ListContourPlot`. Therefore, we have to think a bit harder.

The good thing is, that both plots, with and without label have the same contour-positions (although the colors are different). What I did was to extract the labels from the labeled plot and plug it into the non-labeled, correct-color plot.

Therefore, first thing in the function above is to create a labeled and non-labeled plot of `data` and supply all other options to the call. Then, there is the tricky part. The labels are basically `Text` objects, but since the plot is created using a `GraphicsComplex`, the position of the `Text` is not a coordinate, but an ID which refers to a coordinate. This list of real coordinates is given as first parameter to `GraphicsComplex` and with the call

```
MapIndexed[First[#2] -> #1 &, 
 First@Cases[grlabl, {{_Real, _Real} ..}, {2}]]
```

I extract all real-tuples (which are the coordinates) and make a list like `{1->{x1,y1}, 2->{x2,y2}, ...`. With these rules, I can replace the ID in all the `Text` objects with real coordinates. So what's left to do is to:

*take the unlabeled graphics `gr` and append to the `snd` element of `GraphicsComplex` in it the `Text` objects where I have replaced the IDs with real coordinates*

```
gr /. GraphicsComplex[fst_, snd_] :> 
  GraphicsComplex[fst, 
   Append[snd, 
    Cases[grlabl, Text[__], Infinity] /. 
     Text[what_, pt_] :> Text[what, pt /. pts]]]
```

I can imagine, that even with the explanations it is hard to follow for users which are not experienced with replacement and extraction in Mathematica-expressions. I can only give the advise, that it **is** worth understanding this in order to be equipped doing this alone the next time.

I suggest, to go through the explanation again while looking at the output of this:

```
data = Table[y, {y, 0, 1, 1/99.}, {100}];
ListContourPlot[data, ContourLabels -> True, MaxPlotPoints -> 4] /. 
  x_Real :> N[Round[x]] // InputForm
```

### Additional note to the OPs workaround

The workaround proposed by the OP is indeed very nice. Its disadvantage of using too much memory can be suppressed. When using `ContourShading -> None` and `ContourStyle -> None` no polygons are created although (silly enough) all points are still in the `GraphicsComplex`

```
s5 = Import[
   "https://github.com/downloads/stackmma/Attachments/data_13545.m"];

wl = ListContourPlot[s5, InterpolationOrder -> 6, 
ContourShading -> None, ContourStyle -> None, 
ContourLabels -> True];

nl = ListContourPlot[s5, InterpolationOrder -> 6, 
ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"];
```

We can reduce the size to a minimum by deleting all unnecessary points, leaving only the labels:

```
wl2 = wl /. 
  Graphics[GraphicsComplex[data_, rest_], grest__] :> 
   With[{rules = 
      Dispatch@
       MapIndexed[Text[what_, First[#2]] :> Text[what, #1] &, data]}, 
    Graphics[
     Cases[rest, Text[__], Infinity] /. rules, grest]
    ]

Show[nl,wl2]
```

Comparing the sizes shows the original label-image was 70 times larger

```
ByteCount /@ {wl, wl2}

(* Out[72]= {201936, 2864} *)
```

and `wl2` looks like

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Investigation in the bug

I'm sorry, but the only thing I can do is to investigate in this behavior. I'm using `Linux-x86-64` and Mathematica 8.0.4 here. If someone experience important difference on other systems, feel free to edit.

Let me reduce your problem to a very small example. We use create an array which is constant in `x` direction and makes a linear gradient from 0 to 1 in `y` direction:

```
data = Table[y, {y, 0, 1, 1/99.}, {100}];
```

Will will now use `ListContourPlot` with and without `ContourLabels` and make only very slight changes to the data. What you should know is, that `ColorFunctionScaling` is always turned on per default. Additionally, note that our data does not need to be rescaled because it is already in the right interval. The first simple plot shows the same with and without labels

```
GraphicsRow[
 ListContourPlot[data, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
    ContourLabels -> #] & /@ {True, False}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If we scale our data a bit by using `0.1*data` we only have values from [0,0.1]. Here the plots still look like the above one

```
GraphicsRow[
 ListContourPlot[.1 data, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
    ContourLabels -> #] & /@ {True, False}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now, we add a constant and we use `data+1` and this is the point where the fun starts

```
GraphicsRow[
 ListContourPlot[data + 1, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
    ContourLabels -> #] & /@ {True, False}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

From this point, it only gets worse. Let's say we combine the first and second step and scale *and* add a constant: `.1 data + 1`. This results in

```
GraphicsRow[
 ListContourPlot[.1 data + 1, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
    ContourLabels -> #] & /@ {True, False}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Please be aware, how simple it is, to rescale (which `ColorFunctionScaling` should do) this data to [0,1].

### Extract *rescaled* values

Using `Reap` and `Sow` we can extract the used color-values in the plot. Let's do this for the last ugly example:

```
Last@Reap[
  ListContourPlot[0.1*data + 1, 
   ColorFunction -> 
    Function[f, Sow[f]; ColorData["TemperatureMap", f]], 
   ContourLabels -> True]]

(*
{{0.,0.922727,0.931818,0.940909,0.95,0.959091,0.968182,0.977273,0.986364,0.995455,1.}} 
*)
```

What a mess. This is nothing close to *scaling the colors*. One can surely make further experiments, but I think a bug-report to Wolfram is the best (I would do that for non-obvious reasons).

Comment: But what about the very sudden jump between 6 and 6.2 in the bottom left corner?

Comment: @user141603 Good point. Let me think again about it.

Answer (score 3):

Workaround in a nutshell

```
Show[
  ListContourPlot[s5, InterpolationOrder -> 6, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"],
  ListContourPlot[s5, InterpolationOrder -> 6, ContourStyle -> None, 
    ContourShading -> None, ContourLabels -> True]
]
```

This also works for `ContourPlot`.

Answer (score 1):

Grabbing the code from the OP, in `13.2.0` there are no inconstistencies

```
s5 = Import[
   "https://github.com/downloads/stackmma/Attachments/data_13545.m"];
ListContourPlot[s5, InterpolationOrder -> 6, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", ContourLabels -> True, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> True]
```

> [image: screen]