# Issues with contour labelling

Tags: plotting, bugs

**Bug introduced in 8 or earlier and fixed in 13.1.0**

At least two previous questions, [109778](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/109778/1063) and [13545](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13545/1063), have identified bugs in contour labelling.  Here are two more.  I would welcome workarounds that do not require a completely customized approach.

In the course of generating the plot in my answer to question [258180](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/258180/1063), I noticed that the `ToolTip` incorrectly identified contour values.  Adding the option, `ContourLabels -> All,` (to make the issue more visible) produced the same result for contour labels.  Specifically,

```
ctr = {1/2, 0, -(1/2), -((Sqrt[Pi] Gamma[4/3])/(2 Gamma[5/6])), -0.902182, -1.40218, -1.90218};
ComplexContourPlot[Im[Hypergeometric2F1[1/3, 1/2, 4/3, I z^3] z], 
    {z, -4 - 6 I, 4 + 2 I}, Contours -> N@ctr, ContourShading -> None, ContourLabels -> All, 
    ContourStyle -> {Red, Orange, Brown, Green, Blue, Cyan, Magenta}]
```

[image]

The seven curves are correctly labeled.  In order from the top, they are `{0.5, 0, -0.5, -0.701091, -0.902182, -1.40218, -1.90218}`.  However, when `N` is not applied to `ctr`,

```
ComplexContourPlot[Im[Hypergeometric2F1[1/3, 1/2, 4/3, I z^3] z], 
    {z, -4 - 6 I, 4 + 2 I}, Contours -> ctr, ContourShading -> None, ContourLabels -> All, 
    ContourStyle -> {Red, Orange, Brown, Green, Blue, Cyan, Magenta}]
```

[image]

the labels are incorrect. In order from the top, they are `{1/2, 0, -(1/2), -((Sqrt[Pi] Gamma[4/3])/(2 Gamma[5/6])), -0.902182, -1.40218, -1.90218}`.

A second, perhaps related, issue is based on question [109778](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/109778/1063).  Replace `0.7` by `0.707` in the code for the first plot of the question, and the resulting plot is labeled as one would expect.  However, if `0.7` is replaced by `Sqrt[2]/2`, that label is omitted from the plot, and some other contours are mislabeled.

```
dat = Table[Re[Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2]], {x, -1.1, 1.1, 0.01}, {y, -1.1, 1.1, 0.01}];
ListContourPlot[dat, Contours -> {1., 0.9, 0.8, Sqrt[2]/2, 0.6, 0.5}, ContourLabels -> All]
```

[image]

So, are these bugs and what are convenient workarounds?

Comment: There is a standard [bugs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tags/bugs/info) header that is supposed to have a fixed syntax to facilitate an automatic bugs tracker. I don't know if anyone still uses the tracker, and it's rather difficult to get users to stick to the syntax. I don't much care anymore, because it's like swimming upstream. But since you went to the trouble of approximating the header, I thought I might point out that it doesn't conform to the specified syntax, in case it matters to you. Cheers,

Comment: @MichaelE2 - I have made the correction.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A work-around:** Use `Contours -> N @ ctr`  to set the contour levels and use two custom functions to replace the numerical contour and tooltip labels with `ctr` in setting `ContourLabels`:

```
ClearAll[contourLabelsF, contourTooltipsF]

contourLabelsF[clist_] := Text[AssociationThread[N@clist, clist] @ N @ #3, {#, #2}] &;

contourTooltipsF[clist_] := Tooltip[#, AssociationThread[N @ clist, clist] @ N @ #2] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
ComplexContourPlot[Im[Hypergeometric2F1[1/3, 1/2, 4/3, I z^3] z], 
 {z, -4 - 6 I, 4 + 2 I}, 
 Contours -> N @ctr, 
 ContourShading -> None, 
 ContourLabels -> {contourLabelsF[ctr], contourTooltipsF[ctr]}, 
 ContourStyle -> {Red, Orange, Brown, Green, Blue, Cyan, Magenta}, 
 ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

```
dat = Table[Re[Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2]], {x, -1.1, 1.1, 0.01}, {y, -1.1, 1.1, 0.01}];

ctrs = {1., 0.9, 0.8, Sqrt[2]/2, 0.6, 0.5};

ListContourPlot[dat, 
 Contours -> N @ ctrs, 
 ContourLabels -> {contourLabelsF[ctrs], contourTooltipsF[ctrs]}, 
 ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**An alternative work-around:** Use `Contours -> N @ ctr` and `ContourLabels -> All` to set the contour levels and labels, and post-process the output to replace numerical contour and tooltip labels with `ctr`:

```
ClearAll[postProcess]
postProcess[clist_] := Module[{asso = AssociationThread[N@clist, clist]}, 
   ReplaceAll[{Tooltip[a_, b_] :> Tooltip[a, asso @ b], 
     Text[a_, b___] :> Text[asso @ N @ a, b]}]];
```

***Examples:***

```
postProcess[ctr] @
  ComplexContourPlot[Im[Hypergeometric2F1[1/3, 1/2, 4/3, I z^3] z], 
    {z, -4 - 6 I, 4 + 2 I}, 
    Contours -> N @ctr, 
    ContourShading -> None, 
    ContourLabels -> All, 
    ContourStyle -> {Red, Orange, Brown, Green, Blue, Cyan, Magenta}, 
    ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

```
dat = Table[Re[Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2]], {x, -1.1, 1.1, 0.01}, {y, -1.1, 1.1, 0.01}];

ctrs = {1., 0.9, 0.8, Sqrt[2]/2, 0.6, 0.5};
    
postProcess[ctrs] @
  ListContourPlot[dat, Contours -> N[ctrs], ContourLabels -> All, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]